# WSO2 script mediator Payload append child

Tags: javascript, wso2, payload, mediator, wso2-esb

i'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and in particular way i'm facing up to script mediator. I need to resolve a doubt.
I need to build a payload made like this way:

```
<response>
    <urls>
        <url>http://myfirsturl</url>
        <url>http://mysecondurl</url>
        <url>>http://mythirdurl</url>
    </urls>
</response>
```

In my script mediator i wrote this snippet code:

```
<script language="js">
        ...
        ...
        var clinvarPayload = <response><urls></urls></response>

        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
            clinvarPayload..*::urls.url = myArray[i]                  
        }          

        mc.setPayloadXML(clinvarPayload);
```

My problem is that after the end of the for loop i get the response containing just the last myArray element, i.e:

```
<response>
    <urls>
        <url>http://mythirdurl</url>            
    </urls>
</response>
```

What's wrong with my code?
How can i append the myArray elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appendChild method to add a new node or += operator

See [this](http://wso2.com/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html) : **Modifying XML**